# Build dictionary from list contents (values) and sequential letters as keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to iterate through a list (of unknown length) and build a dictionary with the values being the list contents and the keys assigned sequentially (a, b, c etc etc)

I've got this far:

```
>>> import itertools; import string
>>> names = ['bob', 'fred', 'tracy'] 
>>> abc = string.ascii_lowercase
>>> letter = itertools.cycle(abc)
>>> [ dict(zip(letter.next(), n)) for n in names ]
[{'a': 'b'}, {'b': 'f'}, {'c': 't'}]
```

When I want

```
[{'a': 'bob'}, {'b': 'fred'}, {'c': 'tracy'}]
```

Comment: Why are you zipping them: `{letter.next(): n}`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary The end result is a list of single-item dictionaries. Didn’t see that myself at first either.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger OP wants a list of dicts :)

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes, realized that after posting the comment(now edited). But it's strange they want to repeat the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply this way:

```
>>> [dict(zip(letter, names))]
[{'a': 'bob', 'c': 'tracy', 'b': 'fred'}]
```

Comment: `[{'a': 'bob'}, {'b': 'fred'}, {'c': 'tracy'}]` is not the same as `[{'a': 'bob', 'c': 'tracy', 'b': 'fred'}]`

Comment: @thefourtheye: that's true, thanks, I didn't notice before.  Well, I'll leave this answer here in case the OP finds it useful anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Almost! The `zip` breaks your names though, so you could pass a list of a 2-tuple to `dict`, like this:

```
>>> [ dict([(next(letter), n)]) for n in names ]
[{'a': 'bob'}, {'b': 'fred'}, {'c': 'tracy'}]
```

Or, you could use a dictionary comprehension to build each dictionary, allowing you to save some boilerplate stuff:

```
>>> [ { next(letter): n } for n in names ]
[{'a': 'bob'}, {'b': 'fred'}, {'c': 'tracy'}]
```

Note that I’m using [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) instead of `iterator.next` as that’s how iterators are consumed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['bob', 'fred', 'tracy'] 
abc = string.ascii_lowercase
dct={}
for x,y in zip(abc,names):
    dct[x]=y
print (dct)
```

Also will work. You don't have to worry about lenght of it ( as @AshwiniChaudhary says we assume you already know you can use only 26 items, because this is the lenght of English alphabet). `zip()` function for matching them one by one and defining them key/value of dict. 
Output:

```
>>> 
{'a': 'bob', 'b': 'fred', 'c': 'tracy'}
>>>
```

Or a one-liner;

```
a=[dict(zip(abc, names))]
print (a)
```

Comment: `[{'a': 'bob'}, {'b': 'fred'}, {'c': 'tracy'}]` is not the same as `[{'a': 'bob', 'c': 'tracy', 'b': 'fred'}]`

Comment: Note that this is not what OP is looking for, if number of names are greater than 26 then they want to repeat the keys.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary He gave us `string.ascii_lowercase` so what can we do?

Comment: @howaboutNO They are repeatedly cycling through its items in case the names are more than 26, so `[{'a': 'foo'}, <..25items..>, {'a': 'bar'}]` is a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import izip, cycle
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters
names = ['bob', 'fred', 'tracy'] 
[{k[0]:k[1]} for k in izip(cycle(letters),names)]
```

`izip` returns a tuple like this: `('a' , 'bob')`
Then you can simply create a dictionary by using `k[0]` and `k[1]`.

Comment: how about "from itertools import izip"?